# How to change TTL when using swr in Nuxt 3? (per-route preferably)

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3, ttl

The Nuxt 3 documentations says that `swr enables a static build, that lasts for a configurable TTL`, however, nowhere was I able to find how exactly one would change the TTL & whether it can be set per-route. Is that possible? If so, how?

I've looked at github & also tried to find it in Vite / Nitro documentation but didn't find anything.

I found something about image TTL in Nitro config source files but I suppose that's not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some investigation & experimenting, I found out that it is possible to adjust the TTL already! You just set it to an integer value instead of a boolean.

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    routeRules: {
        '/**': { swr: 5  }, //  TTL in seconds
    }
})
```

Comment: Sorry if my answer wasn't specific enough regarding the seconds.

Comment: No problem, I'm just having trouble with specifying it to work only for some routes. When I enable it on '/test-swr': { swr: 5 }, it doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: Is `/test-swr` specified above or below `/**`? Try putting it above.

Comment: seem like no matter where I put it, the `/**` overrides the TTL for all routes
this is what it looks like:
`
routeRules: {
        '/no-swr/time-test': { swr: 0 },
        '/**': { swr: 10 },
    }
`
and when I only enable it for a specific route, it stays disabled
`
    routeRules: {
        '/time-test': { swr: 10 },
    }
`

Comment: @Matej where do you host your app? I was told swr works on Netlify only and would like to check that. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidDahan there are several places where SWR may be working, mainly most of the Edge Rendering (SSR) places like Cloudflare workers, Vercel etc IMO.

Comment: @kissu thanks I was wondering because on [this page](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#route-rules)  I can read both `currently Netlify and Vercel are supported` and `currently enables full incremental static generation on Netlify, with Vercel coming soon`. So I'm not sure if Vercel is actually supported.

Comment: @DavidDahan ISR is not the same as SWR and I think that it should be supported indeed.

Answer (score 2):

This [github issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/16078) is about that subject, it is still in the works (you can subscribe to it to get the latest updates!) but this is how the whole final API may look like:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  routes: {
    '/': { prerender: true },
    '/blog/*': { static: true },
    '/stats/*': { swr: '10 min' }, //  TTL of 10 minutes
    '/admin/*': { ssr: false },
    '/react/*': { redirect: '/vue' },
  }
})
```

Comment: The API only accepts a boolean or a number for swr. The number is the number of seconds.